# How to control Rails app requests to external api?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building a Rails 4 (postgres) app on the back of a third party API. For now, the third party API allows with 100 requests per min.

The roundtrip for the user takes about 2000 ms so I want to move this into a worker.

I considered using sidekiq, but with each new user and new background thread comes the possibility that I'll exceed my API quota.

What is the best way to control my applications interaction with the third party API? Do I need a single serial queue to control the rate limit effectively?

Comment: 100rpm per IP per account or per what?

Comment: 100 rpm per application I've registered with them (client id & client secret) So this quota is for my entire app.

Comment: so why dont you register 25 accounts and then use just randomly one ? let me guess, that won't work?

wenn you need to have a counter and after 100 requests you just create a new que for sidekick which will be processed next hour . but i mean, its going into the deeeeeep future. 1000 requests pending, so my one is be done in 11 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you'll get an error (like exception) when you are over the 100 requests limit. If all API requests are in a sidekiq worker, the worker will automatically retry on error. Initially the retry will be quite soon, but you can overwrite the retry time with something like:

```
sidekiq_retry_in do
  rand(60..75)
end
```

In this way each retry will be 60 to 75 seconds after the error.
You can check more about sidekiq's error handling here: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This certainly helps control the requests but I'll have to combine with some other approaches too before it feels robust